# Product reviews to display even if zero reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, product-review

In magento 1.9.3.1 on the category list page and also on the actual product view page, it displays the stars and 1 Review(s) : add your review

now this only shows up if there are reviews, anyone know how i can get this to display even if there are no reviews i.e.

the grey stars then 0 review(s) : add your review

as i want to remove the tabs with the reviews at the bottom

---

there are two of those statements, and i have tried changed one at a time and even both and it doesnt work for me

```
  <?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
    <div class="ratings">
        <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
            <div class="rating-box">
                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
            </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <p class="rating-links">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a>
            <span class="separator">|</span>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Add Your Review') ?></a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
    <p class="no-rating"><a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `app\design\frontend\package_name\theme_name\template\review\helper\summary.phtml` change the condition `if ($this->getReviewsCount()):` to `if ($this->getReviewsCount() >= 0)`